# Structured JSON layout

Tags: php, json

I'm working with JSON by PHP at the moment, when I encode it, it would output as:

```
{"username":"ND","email":"test@email.com","regdate":"8th June 2010","other":{"alternative":"ND"},"level":"6"}
```

When I would like it to output like this:

```
{
    "username": "ND",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "regdate": "8th June 2010",
    "other":
    {
        "alternative": "ND"
    },
    "level":"6"
}
```

So that me and my other developers can read it well enough when structured. How can I do this?

Example also like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

Cheers

Comment: I recommend using better tools to view the data instead of trying to format it for output. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869/

Comment: Agreed with @David. Firebug lets you navigate JSON as a tree, as well. Very useful.

Comment: Are you trying to encode already well formed JSON with json_encode() before you decode it, since that would produce the result above? - see my edit below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could find this useful myself, so here's a little function I wrote:

```
<?php
function json_pretty_encode($obj)
{
 $json = json_encode($obj);
 if (!$json) return $json;

 $f = '';
 $len = strlen($json);

 $depth = 0;
 $newline = false;

 for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
 {
  if ($newline)
  {
   $f .= "\n";
   $f .= str_repeat(' ', $depth);
   $newline = false;
  }

  $c = $json[$i];
  if ($c == '{' || $c == '[')
  {
   $f .= $c;
   $depth++;
   $newline = true;
  }
  else if ($c == '}' || $c == ']')
  {
   $depth--;
   $f .= "\n";
   $f .= str_repeat(' ', $depth);
   $f .= $c;
  }
  else if ($c == '"')
  {
   $s = $i;
   do {
    $c = $json[++$i];
    if ($c == '\\')
    {
     $i += 2;
     $c = $json[$i];
    }
   } while ($c != '"');
   $f .= substr($json, $s, $i-$s+1);
  }
  else if ($c == ':')
  {
   $f .= ': ';
  }  
  else if ($c == ',')
  {
   $f .= ',';
   $newline = true;
  }
  else
  {
   $f .= $c;
  }
 }

 return $f;
}
?>
```

It's naive, trusting that PHP will return a valid JSON string. It could be written more concisely, but it's easy to modify this way. (And of course this adds unnecessary overhead in production scenarios where only a machine reads the text.)

Edit: Added an else clause to catch numbers and other unknown chars.

Comment: If you think it is naive to trust that PHP will produce JSON when the built in JSON function is used … how can you trust PHP enough to use it at all?

Comment: @David, I just meant it as a warning not to pull that code out for arbitrary parsing of JSON, as it expects the format that PHP supplies.
@Peter, This is an encoder. You need to pass it an object to convert into JSON.

Comment: @Konforce - Sorry, brain freeze. I was just thinking about json_decode.

Comment: Are you gonna throw in bitmasking support?  ;) http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I tried this function, and it does format nicely, but it's broken. Unfortunately it's hard to find out where, but I've run into cases where `json_encode` output parsed back into objects fine, but your `json_pretty_encode` didn't. I think it has something to do with escaped characters, but am not sure where exactly.

Comment: @Joren: If you provided a sample string that breaks, I could see if it was a simple fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, the input I had was too large and the parser error too unhelpful to debug your code with. When I take the time to figure out a small reproduction, I'll let you know. :)

Comment: I 'edited' your answer (no changes) so that I could undo my downvote, which I figured wasn't fair as long as I'm not 100% sure the problem wasn't actually my own fault.

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.4.0 Alpha1, you can easily do it like:

```
$data = array (
  'username' => 'ND',
  'email' => 'test@email.com',
  'regdate' => '8th June 2010',
  'other' =>
  array (
    'alternative' => 'ND',
  ),
  'level' => '6',
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),"\n";
```

The output is:

```
{
    "username": "ND",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "regdate": "8th June 2010",
    "other": {
        "alternative": "ND"
    },
    "level": "6"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to install json_xs tool and use it in couple with curl:
curl -X GET http://some.re/sour/se/name.json | json_xs

Answer (score -2):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```